# Дано целое число N (> 0). Используя операции деления нацело и взятия остатка от деления, найти число, полученное при прочтении числа N справа налево

Tags: c++builder

> Дано целое число N (> 0). Используя операции деления нацело и взятия остатка от деления, найти число, полученное при прочтении числа N справа налево.

Программа:

```
#inсlude <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int n, s, k, l;
    cout << " vvedite n: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 0) {
    if (k = n % 10)
        s = s + k n = n / 10;
    }
    cout << " symma= ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << " kolishestvo= ";
    cin >> l;
    getch();
}
```

Как записать правильно условие, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо просто выделять десятичные **цифры** справа и строить из них число.

if не нужен

```
s = 0;
while (n) {
  s = s*10+n%10; n /= 10;
}
cout << "summa = "<<s<<"\n";
```

summa, это конечно странное название для ответа. palindrome лучше отражает суть задачи.

Что непонятно, спрашивайте

Comment: программа все равно не срабатывает, выдает ошибку

Comment: @IvAn, уточняйте, что за ошибку выдает. глядя на Ваш код, неудивительно, у Вас ведь банально ";" между операциями не стоит. Пример, который Вам дали, должен работать.

Comment: теперь я все понял

Comment: @IvAn, а принять ответ, в таком случае, не хотите? Это делается путем нажатия на галку ;)